# Посоветуйте варианты создания поочередной анимации для сайта

Tags: javascript, svg, анимация, svg-animation

Мне необходимо сделать несложную (в плане длительности - 1 минута) svg-анимацию(2D). Объекты - элементарные: прямоугольники, линии, круги. Могут перемещаться.

Перебрал много js-библиотек, но еще не наткнулся на такую, чтобы могла реализовать: 
Объект 1 движется. → Движение завершилось. → Объект 2 движется. → Движение завершилось... и т.д.

Пока остановился на anime.js и идее: реализовать цепочку функций, и после завершения необходимого движения, вызывать след. функцию.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" style="border:1px solid gray;" >   
 <g>  
 <circle id="crc1" cx="40" cy="50" r="20" fill="crimson" > 
   <animate attributeName="cx"  values="40;300" dur="4s" fill="freeze" /> 
 </circle>  
     <circle id="crc2" cx="40" cy="150" r="20" fill="gold" >
          <animate attributeName="cx"  values="40;300" dur="4s" fill="freeze" /> 
     </circle>  
 <circle id="crc3" cx="40" cy="250" r="20" fill="greenyellow" >
       <animate attributeName="cx"  values="40;300" dur="4s" fill="freeze" /> 
 </circle>  
    
  </g> 
 <g id="gO1" transform="translate(100,260)">
              <rect x="45" y="85" height="24" width="60" rx="5" fill="green"  />
           <text x="60" y="102" font-size="18" fill="gold">Start</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Мне кажеться нужно перефразировать вопрос, потому как он не будет иметь однозначного ответа.

Comment: А почему именно svg анимацию?

Comment: В svg можно запускать следующую анимацию по завершению текущей. А из библиотек greensock кажется неплох для таких анимаций.

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий.

Comment: @Look_at_meow Добавьте, пожалуйста код своей попытки. Пусть это будет неработающий код, зато будет отправная точка для решения вопроса. Ваш вопрос интересен, обязательно будет ответ и после вашей правки, я надеюсь вопрос откроют

Answer (score 4):

Для простых анимаций, а если с фантазией хорошо, то и для средних, можно использовать анимации, которые доступны в ccs3. В гугл ccs3 анимации.

Comment: судя по всему, вам тут тоже не рады. Ловите от меня +1, иначе подумаете что тут одни звери обитают и ждут когда же можно будет кого-то заминусовать :)

Comment: не знаю, почему могут быть не рады. css3 вполне достаточно, чтобы реализовать то, что хочет автор вопроса

Comment: @Pavel, просто ответ больше на комментарий похож... Но на самом деле здесь сам вопрос такой - вон его уже закрыли.

Answer (score 3):

Anime.js отличная библиотека, не зря вы на ней остановились. В ней есть все необходимое для реализации вашей задачи. Очень удобно работать с svg как с целыми объектами, так и их с частями.

Для вашей задачи я бы использовал anime.timeline() вместо цепочки функций, управляя последовательностью анимации через абсолютный или относительный offset, чтобы добиться желаемого результата.

Лично я бы выбрал одну из 2х библиотек: Anime.js или GreenSock.

Comment: Pavel, не советую отвечать на подобные вопросы...    В итоге выйдет куча обсуждений с нулевым КПД....

Comment: Человек выбрал инструмент и хочет его использовать посредством колбеков, я его поправил, не вижу ничего плохого в этом. Именно из-за таких комментов, как к вопросу, а так же минусовке, SO имеет репутацию недружелюблого сообщества https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7219/stackoverflow-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C.

Comment: Дело в том, что в след. раз я не только не буду отвечать, мне будет лень даже смотреть большинство вопросов.

Comment: Поиск разного рода библиотек и тому подобных, запрещен на сайте...

Comment: Прочитайте еще раз вопрос. Варианты создания анимации, в данном случае я советую использовать определенный и правильный метод, с точки зрения решения задачи.

Comment: Pavel, у данного вопроса может быть миллион вариантов реализации...

Comment: Вот какая мне мысль только что пришла: если вы не советуете отвечать, возможно, тогда вам лучше предпринимать какие-то меры по удалению или модерации вопросов такого рода? Обозначать их как-то, нет? Если по вашему мнению они не точные и общие? Может быть предпринять какие-то меры будет лучше чем просто наставить минусов ко всем отвечающим?

Answer (score 2):

Нравятся анимации SVG? Но не знаете с какой стороны к ним подступиться?

Поэтому ищите библиотеки, реализующие анимации SVG. Да, это решение, но очень трудно не понимая основ анимации SVG, сразу использовать библиотеки. Любая ошибка в исходном коде SVG помешает срабатыванию библиотеки.

Поэтому необходимо, прежде чем приступить к использованию библиотек, немного разобраться в `pure SVG` и `smil`

**Реализация этого сценария:**

> Объект 1 движется. → Движение завершилось. → Объект 2 движется. →
> Движение завершилось... и т.д.

Берем пример из вопроса и реализуем цепочку выполнения последовательных анимаций с помощью атрибута `begin`

1. `begin="start.click"` - анимация начнется после клика по кнопке 'start'
2. `begin="an_crc1.end"`  - вторая анимация начнется после окончания первой анимации `an_crc1`
3. `begin="an_crc2.end"`  - третья анимация начнется после окончания второй анимации `an_crc2`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 550 550" style="border:1px solid gray;" >   
 <g>    
<circle id="crc1" cx="40" cy="50" r="20" fill="crimson" > 
  <animate id="an_crc1"
          attributeName="cx"
          values="40;350"
          begin="start.click"
          dur="1s"
          fill="freeze" /> 
    </circle>  
    <circle id="crc2" cx="40" cy="150" r="20" fill="gold" >
       <animate id="an_crc2"
                attributeName="cx"
                values="40;350"
                begin="an_crc1.end"
                dur="1s"
                fill="freeze" /> 
      </circle>  
 <circle id="crc3" cx="40" cy="250" r="20" fill="greenyellow" >
      <animate id="an_crc3"
             attributeName="cx"
             values="40;350"
             begin="an_crc2.end"
             dur="1s"
             fill="freeze" /> 
</circle>  
       
  </g>  
    <g id="start" transform="translate(100,-80)">
              <rect x="45" y="85" height="24" width="60" rx="5" fill="green"  />
           <text x="60" y="102" font-size="18" fill="gold">Start</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Изменяя параметры атрибута можно получить разные сценарии. Например запускается первый круг, после задержки равной 1 секунде, запускаются одновременно два других круга

1. `begin="start.click"` - анимация начнется после клика по кнопке 'start'
2. `begin="start.click+1s"`  - вторая анимация начнется после начала первой анимации с задержкой `1s`
3. `begin="start.click+1s"`  - третья анимация начнется после начала первой анимации с задержкой `1s`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 500 500" style="border:1px solid gray;" >   
 <g>    
<circle id="crc1" cx="40" cy="50" r="20" fill="crimson" > 
  <animate id="an_crc1"
        attributeName="cx"
        values="40;350;40"
        begin="start.click"
        dur="2s"
        fill="freeze" /> 
    </circle>  
    <circle id="crc2" cx="40" cy="150" r="20" fill="gold" >
         <animate id="an_crc2"
                attributeName="cx"
                values="40;350;40"
                begin="start.click+1s"
                dur="2s" fill="freeze" /> 
        </circle>  
    <circle id="crc3" cx="40" cy="250" r="20" fill="greenyellow" >
      <animate id="an_crc3"
              attributeName="cx"
              values="40;350;40"
              begin="start.click+1s"
              dur="2s" fill="freeze" /> 
    </circle>  
       
  </g>  
    <g id="start" transform="translate(100,-80)">
              <rect x="45" y="85" height="24" width="60" rx="5" fill="green"  />
           <text x="60" y="102" font-size="18" fill="gold">Start</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

**Закольцовывание анимации**

После окончания последней (третьей) анимации должна начаться первая анимация

`begin="start.click;an_crc3.end"`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 550 550" style="border:1px solid gray;" >   
 <g>    
    <circle id="crc1" cx="40" cy="50" r="20" fill="crimson" > 
      <animate id="an_crc1"
           attributeName="cx"
           values="40;350;40"
           begin="start.click;an_crc3.end"
           dur="2s"
           fill="freeze" /> 
    </circle>  
        <circle id="crc2" cx="40" cy="150" r="20" fill="gold" >
           <animate id="an_crc2"
                  attributeName="cx"
                  values="40;350;40"
                  begin="an_crc1.end"
                  dur="2s"
                  fill="freeze" /> 
        </circle>  
    <circle id="crc3" cx="40" cy="250" r="20" fill="greenyellow" >
          <animate id="an_crc3"
               attributeName="cx"
               values="40;350;40"
               begin="an_crc2.end"
               dur="2s" fill="freeze" /> 
    </circle>  
       
  </g>  
    <g id="start" transform="translate(100,-80)">
              <rect x="45" y="85" height="24" width="60" rx="5" fill="green"  />
           <text x="60" y="102" font-size="18" fill="gold">Start</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```